# Drawing a indian flag chakra in python turtlee

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am drawing the Indian flag using turtle and python. I have got the rectangles and colours down so far, but am struggling to make the chakra in the middle.

It has 24 spokes, and is surrounded by a closed circle. Any tips on how to accomplish this?

This is my code now:

```
import turtle

def drawRectangle (t, w, h, c):
    t.fillcolor(c)
    t.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        t.forward(h)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(w)
        t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()


def main ():
    wn = turtle.Screen()

    chloe = turtle.Turtle()
    drawRectangle(chloe,50,200, "chartreuse3")

    chloe.up()
    chloe.goto(0,-100)
    chloe.down()

    drawRectangle(chloe,50,200, "orange1")

    chloe.up()
    chloe.goto(100,-25)
    chloe.down()
    chloe.pencolor("blue4")

    for i in range(24):
        chloe.forward(20)
        chloe.backward(20)
        chloe.left(15)
    chloe.up()
    chloe.goto(300,300)

main()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. You could get better reception for your question if you add some of your code here.

Comment: Any tips we could give you beyond "use the `forward`, `backward`, `right`, and `left` functions" would be to just write it for you.  What have you tried?  We can help you if you're stuck with a specific problem.

Comment: So I think I got it to work in general using the basic functions. I wish I could put a circle around it, but I'm not sure how to do that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`circle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle) to draw the circle:

```
chloe.pencolor("blue4")

# draw the spokes
for i in range(24):
    chloe.forward(20)
    chloe.backward(20)
    chloe.left(15)

# raise pen
chloe.up()

# head down
chloe.setheading(270)

# go forward 20
chloe.forward(20)

# reset heading
chloe.setheading(0)

# pen down
chloe.down()

# draw the circle
chloe.circle(20)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import turtle
def drawRectangle (t, l, b, c):
    t.fillcolor(c)
    t.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        t.forward(b)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(l)
        t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()


def main ():
   wn = turtle.Screen()

   india = turtle.Turtle()
   drawRectangle(india,50,200, "orange1")
   india.up()
   india.goto(0,-100)
   india.down()
   drawRectangle(india,50,200, "green")
   india.up()
   india.goto(100,-20)
   india.down()
   india.pencolor("blue3")

   for i in range(24):
    india.forward(20)
    india.backward(20)
    india.left(15)
    india.up()
    india.goto(400,400)

main()
```